# RShiny print current page

Tags: r, shiny

How can I print the current page in R shiny web applications? It is possible in HTML by using the command of window.print();. But I could not find and implement its correspondent R Shiny command. What is on my mind is something like the following? How can I call an html command in SERVER?

```
actionButton("print", "PRINT")

server <- function(input, output) {

        observeEvent(input$print, {
          window.print();
        })
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done using `shinyjs` package to call a js function.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("winprint")),
  actionButton("print", "PRINT")
  ))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$print, {
    js$winprint()
   })
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the result be identical to just using the browser's native "Print page" command?

Comment: Yes @rvrvrv. That was the requirement as per the question asked.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm trying to find a way to print the page while preserving all graphs (browser's in-built Print cuts things off) so was wondering whether this might have solved my problem!

Comment: This solution no longer works. Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided

Comment: Updated  `functions = c("winprint")` in `extendShinyjs()` to make it work.