# Print Shiny App Screen not working Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that has a print screen button, but after updating the shinyjs package, the code no longer works.

I got this solution from [RShiny print current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459361/rshiny-print-current-page) and it used to work, but not any more.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(V8)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  actionButton("print", "PRINT")
))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$print, {
    js$winprint()
  })
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But I get the below error now and the app won't deploy anymore.

```
Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided
```

Answer (score 14):

Please try

```
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("winprint")),
```

instead of

```
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
```

in your `ui`.